# Using a subset of all defined relations

Tags: alloy

```
module test

sig Foo {}

sig A {
    b: set B,
    foo: one Foo
}

sig B {
    foo: one Foo
}

assert foo {
    all s: (univ - Foo) | all rel: (univ - Foo) -> (univ - Foo) |
    s not in s.*rel
}

check foo for 2
```

Suppose I'm trying to define a relation within an assert that says "apart from Foo and the relations that include Foo, there are no cycles" (which is trivially true by inspection here).

The assert above creates some `$foo_rel` relations which aren't defined originally in the model. How do I restrict it to only the relations I've specified in my `sig`s?

Comment: It would help if you provide a runnable model and more details about the output. I am not sure I understand what you tried to achieve. If you have actual output, you can describe what you want different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added an example which (hopefully) makes the question more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$foo_rel` and `$foo_s` are introduced due to skolemization since you're doing a quantification over an arity 2 tuple. (Personally, I've so far ignored the details of skolemization and only hate it when it doesn't work.)

However, I do not think that is your problem. I ran the model without integers:

```
check foo for 2 but 0 int
```

This gave the following solution:

```
---INSTANCE---
integers={}
univ={B$0, Foo$0}
Int={}
seq/Int={}
String={}
none={}
this/Foo={Foo$0}
this/A={}
this/A<:b={}
this/A<:foo={}
this/B={B$0}
this/B<:foo={B$0->Foo$0}
skolem $foo_s={B$0}
skolem $foo_rel={B$0->B$0}
```

When we go to the evaluator we can do your quantifications step by step:

```
> univ-Foo
┌──┐
│B⁰│
└──┘
> (univ - Foo) -> (univ - Foo)
┌──┬──┐
│B⁰│B⁰│
└──┴──┘
```

It is clear that if you quantify over `all rel: (univ - Foo) -> (univ - Foo)` this will include cycles.

```
> B⁰.*((univ - Foo) -> (univ - Foo))
┌──┐
│B⁰│
└──┘
```

I think there is some misunderstanding of how Alloy models work. I hope this helps to explore these models a bit better?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the evaluator and that definitely helps a lot with experimenting.